# Magento 2 child theme: CSS files not included

Tags: magento2, theme, css, custom

I want to add some CSS files. So I created a child theme.

In Backend the theme is activated.

**theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
   <title>Customtheme</title>
   <parent>Smartwave/porto</parent>
</theme>
```

**Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/styles.css" />
        <css src="css/paymentfont.min.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

**CSS files**

- web/css/styles.css
- web/css/paymentfont.min.css

I cleared the cache, deployed the static data and also reindexed.
The static files were created but not included.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am having the same problem, and so far am not sure why it is occurring. The layout blocks will only extend or override certain XML files (Smartwave_Porto module layout files) and instantly shows changes but any others I've tried are completely ignored.

Comment: In pub/static folder find where is paymentfont.min.css file?

Answer (score 0):

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <css src="css/styles.css" />

</head>
```

Add your CSS in **yourtheme/web/css** path and run Deployed content.

That's it.

Comment: The CSS files are in the following folder: app/design/frontend/Customvendor/customtheme/web/css

Answer (score 0):

I thought this might help as I'm using the same theme. I had couple of issues but finally got my child theme working. Here is my folder structure:

app/design/frontend/vendor/{parent_theme}_child consists of the follow folders:

```
-Magento_Theme

--layout_default_head_blocks.xml

-media

--preview.png

-registration.php

-theme.xml

-web
--css
---style.css
```

Here is the debug:

> - If you child theme is enabled in admin, then the registration is    working, otherwise double check your registration.php and theme.xml.
> - Make sure style.css in the right folder, some tutorials suggest put style.css in child_theme/css/, this doesn't work for me. It needs to
>     be in child_theme/web/css/.
> - Make sure default_header_blocks.xml in    the right folder. Nikul's    answer missing close `</page>` tag.
> - Give  correct file (644) and folder permission(755) to your child    theme.
> - Turn developer mode on, it helps in case of syntax issues.